# Bootstrap grid layout issue when populating with items

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to MVC5 and especially to using Bootstrap. I'm trying to create a website in which the first page should feature a grid with student images. Right now it looks like this. I want to have 5 images per row, but I haven't manage to figure out how(it was either 4, or 6). 
Also when there is no space between the rows and the images stuck together.

I am populating the grid with items from my Student Model.

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="row">

                @foreach (var item in Model.Students)
                {

                    <div class="col-md-2">


                                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Students", new {studentId = item.StudentId})">
                                    <img src="../../@item.ProfileImagePath" alt="Profile Image" />
                                </a>
                            </div>


                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

I didn't fully understand how does the bootstrap grid work, especially when I'm populating it with dynamic data. The website looks like this now
https://i.stack.imgur.com/roQvB.jpg

Comment: For a HTML5/CSS question this has all the wrong tags. The answer won't contain any C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
 <div class="row">
       @foreach (var item in Model.Students)
       {
             <div class="col-md-2">
             ...
             </div>
       }
 </div>
```

Which generates one long `<row>`.  But there is no auto-wrapping, you'll have to break this up into rows yourself.

Assuming that Students is a List<>

```
// roughly, untested
@for(int r = 0; r < Model.Students.Count; r += 5)
{
  <div class="row">  
  @for (int s = r; s < r+5; s += 1)
  {
     <div class="col-md-2">
       // do stuff with Model.Students[s]
     </div>
  }
  </div>
}
```